# Metadata Editing

Tags: c, png

Is there a way to get and modify metadata of a .png file using c/c++?
Every photo taken on a phone has a "creation" and a "last modified" date. Can I somehow change the "last modified" date to the "creation" date?

If this is possible, can I make the program to do this in all the files of a selected folder?

I found this codeblock online using the <sys/stat.h> and <time.h> libraries but i can't figure out how to utilize it.

```
struct stat filestat;

stat("gettysburg.txt",&filestat); /* newline included in ctime() output */
printf(" File access time %s",
        ctime(&filestat.st_atime)
      );
printf(" File modify time %s",
        ctime(&filestat.st_mtime)
      );
printf("File changed time %s",
        ctime(&filestat.st_ctime)
      );
printf("  File birth time %s",
        ctime(&filestat.st_birthtime)
      );
```

Comment: Unix filesystems don't normally have a creation time. `ctime` is the inode change time, not the creation time.

Comment: Are you talking about the *image metadata* as in EXIF, or about the file information - like any file, not just photos? Your code relates to the latter.

Comment: To change the atime or mtime, use the `utimes()` function. You can't change the ctime, except by editing the filesystem itself.

Comment: @EugeneSh. can i use fscanf to get the st_birthtime?

Comment: The Apple file systems on Macs do have a 'birthtime' for files (but they are not 'normal Unix file systems').  You should be able to find a PNG library that would support the operations you want.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages, concentrating on which
questions are ['on-topic'](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
here.
This question is off-topic — one of the close reasons on SO is
_Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more
— This question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers._ You might
be able to ask appropriately on [Software
Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), but check
what is [on-topic](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
there, too.

Comment: Look into [libpng sources](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html) for relevant API.